# Android testing with Espresso add jar error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-espresso

---

I have tried different IDE and OS, but have the same error. Maybe i do something wrong?

***Steps in Intellij Idea Ultimate:***

> 1. Create new Android application project.
> 2. Copy espresso-1.1-bundled.jar in libs folder.
> 3. Add as library.
> 4. Build project.

***Result:***

```
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:215)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:145)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:159)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:244)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
Error:Android Pre Dex: [espresso-1.1-bundled.jar] 1 error; aborting
```

Comment: I have similar problems. Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: no :( I choose robotium. It's not create a had pain for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Make sure you have installed the latest Android Support Repository under Extras (see instructions).
    Open your app’s build.gradle file. This is usually not the top-level build.gradle file but app/build.gradle.
    Add the following lines inside dependencies:

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5
```